# Is $\{ x \in M |\ (f(x),g(x)) \in A \times B\} = \{x \in M |\ f(x) \in A\} \cap \{x \in M | \ g(x) \in B\} $ true?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is the following set equality true?

> $\{ x \in M |\ (f(x),g(x)) \in A \times B\} = \{y \in M |\ f(y) \in A\} \cap \{z \in M | \ g(z) \in B \} $

I would say yes, as the condition placed on members of the set on the l.h.s. is  $(f(x),g(x)) \in A \times B$, which is equivalent to $ f(x) \in A$ and $g(x) \in B$. Therefore the l.h.s should be equal to the intersection. Am I right? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your reasoning is difficult because you're using the same $x$ in multiple places.  On the LHS, you've got the same $x$ in both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  On the RHS, since it might be clearer if you use $y$ in the first set and $z$ in the second.  Now, the given equality is true, but you should start with the standard set equality assumptions to prove it.

Comment: I see that my notation may cause confustion! I wll edit it! Do you suggest I argue by double inclusion instead? Thank you!

Comment: You've got a direct approach if you argue with double inclusion.

Comment: Alright! Double inclusion seems immediate! Thank you for your help!